# How I create a simple Socket.io server for connecting with socket.io-java-client on android app?

Tags: java, android, node.js, websocket, socket.io-1.0

I have a client-side java code running in my Android Activity using the [Gottox/socket.io.-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) implementation on Github. This is the client code that needs to simple connect to a server and receive messages from it from time to time. Please bear with me as I'm very new to this domain and might be understanding this completely wrong!

This is what my client code looks like right now:

```
package com.example.culami;

import io.socket.IOAcknowledge;
import io.socket.IOCallback;
import io.socket.SocketIO;
import io.socket.SocketIOException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class AcknowledgeExample implements IOCallback {
    private SocketIO socket;
    int connectionEstablished;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    /*public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new AcknowledgeExample();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }*/

    public AcknowledgeExample() throws Exception 
    { 
        connectionEstablished = 0;
        socket = new SocketIO();
        socket.connect("http://192.168.0.108:3000/", this);
        //socket.connect("http://localhost:3000/", this);
        // Sends a string to the server.
        //socket.send("Hello Server");

        // Sends a JSON object to the server.
        //socket.send(new JSONObject().put("key", "value").put("key2", "another value"));
        //socket.send("server says hello!");

        // Emits an event to the server.
        //socket.emit("event", "argument1", "argument2", 13.37);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
        System.out.println("an Error occured");
        socketIOException.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection established");
        connectionEstablished = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
        System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
    }

}
```

The server side code I'm currently trying to work with is taken from [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)'s [getting started tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) page and looks as under:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
    //res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
    console.log('a user connected');
    /*socket.on('chat message', function(msg)
    {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });*/
});
```

All I need is to figure out a way to make my client and server codes connect. The server side code needs to be java script as sends the client a string keyword/message from time to time. Any pointers/suggestions/fixes will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I assume the server side also needs a line like http.listen(3000, '192.168.0.108'); ?

Comment: Yes! It would be listening for incoming connections over the network, through a dedicated port like 3000.

Comment: Did you find solution?